# How to vertically align the text and leading/trailing icons in a TextField

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop

Is there a way to set the trailing/leading icons and the text on the same level? On default it is not as shown in the image below. I tried changing the `fontStyle` parameter in `TextField` but no success. The text is shown higher than the icons

[image]

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.material.Icon
import androidx.compose.material.OutlinedTextField
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.ArrowForward
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.window.singleWindowApplication

fun main() = singleWindowApplication {
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("TEXT") }
    
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = { text = it },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        leadingIcon = {
            Icon(contentDescription = null,
                 imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowForward)
        },
        trailingIcon = {
            Icon(contentDescription = null,
                 imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowForward)
        })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several solutions. For desktop Compose, offset the icons. For mobile Compose, adjust the baseline. And finally, just create a custom TextField.

The icons may have extra padding at the bottom. It could also be that the icons and text are always aligned to the top. You could replace the icons with ones that have no bottom padding or shift the icons up. You can tell that the icons are affecting the vertical alignment because if you comment out your icons, the text does center vertically. You could also try reducing the size of the icons.

On desktop Compose, shift the icons up:

```kotlin
OutlinedTextField(
     value = text,
     onValueChange = { text = it },
     modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
     leadingIcon = {
          Icon(
                modifier = Modifier.offset(y = -3.dp),
                contentDescription = null,
                imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowForward
          )
     },
     trailingIcon = {
          Icon(
                modifier = Modifier.offset(y = -3.dp),
                contentDescription = null,
                imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowForward
          )
     })
```

On mobile devices, you can adjust the `baseline` of the text:

```kotlin
OutlinedTextField(
    value = text,
    textStyle = TextStyle(baselineShift = BaselineShift(-0.2f)),
    onValueChange = { text = it },
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    leadingIcon = {
        Icon(
            contentDescription = null,
            imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowForward
        )
    },
    trailingIcon = {
        Icon(
            contentDescription = null,
            imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowForward
        )
    })
```

Here is also a custom TextField:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            CustomTextField(
                initialText = "cool",
                onValueChange = {

                },
                onLeftButtonClick = {

                },
                onRightButtonClick = {

                }
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun CustomTextField(
    initialText: String,
    onValueChange: (text: String) -> Unit,
    onLeftButtonClick: () -> Unit,
    onRightButtonClick: () -> Unit
) {

    var text by remember { mutableStateOf(initialText) }

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier

            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentSize()
            .background(color = Color.White, shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))

            .border(width = 1.dp, shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp), color = Color(0xFF585858))
    ) {

        ConstraintLayout(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        ) {

            val (left, mid, right) = createRefs()

            IconButton(onClick = onLeftButtonClick,
                modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(left) {
                    start.linkTo(parent.start, margin = 10.dp)
                    top.linkTo(parent.top)
                    bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                }) {
                Icon(
                    contentDescription = null,
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowForward,
                )
            }


            IconButton(onClick = onRightButtonClick,
                modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(right) {
                    end.linkTo(parent.end, margin = 10.dp)
                    top.linkTo(parent.top)
                    bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                }) {
                Icon(
                    contentDescription = null,
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowForward,
                )
            }

            TextField(
                value = text,
                onValueChange = {
                    text = it
                    onValueChange(it)
                },
                colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                    backgroundColor = Color.White
                ),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .offset(y = 4.dp)
                    .constrainAs(mid) {
                        start.linkTo(left.end, margin = 10.dp)
                        top.linkTo(parent.top)
                        end.linkTo(right.start, margin = 10.dp)
                        bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                        width = Dimension.fillToConstraints
                    })
        }
    }
```

Comment: I adjusted the baseline as you suggested, but it does not change anything. Tried also with higher values but stays the same

Comment: I only tried it on a mobile device where it works. It probably doesn't work on the desktop version of Compose.

Comment: I updated the code to show an alternative solution for desktop apps.

Comment: thanks, I'll do it this way until there is something that will automatically align everything vertically

Comment: I also added a custom TextField as an alternate solution. You have full control over this.

Comment: I have now also tested my example in Android (which does not work on the desktop) and it works as expected, everything is aligned. There must be a bug in the desktop compose version.